# How to parse a large text file to dataframe and write to parquet using Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm currently trying to parse a big text file containing one column named "value" and want to split it up in multiple columns given fixed width per column.

Input looks like this:

```
value
0000000206001060010001020020722E5549.73177802...
0000000206001060010001120030203E5549.73177802...
0000000206001060010001220030717E5549.73177802..
0000000206001060010001320040714E5549.73177802...
0000000206001060010001420050713E5549.73177802...
0000000206001060010001520060514E5549.73177802...
...
```

I tried to go about it like this:

```
val dfRawInput = spark.read.text("C:/input.txt")
val dfInputColumnized = {
    dfRawInput.select(
      $"value".substr(1,8).cast("string").alias("column1"),
      $"value".substr(9,5).cast("string").alias("column2"),
      ...
      $"value".substr(x,y).cast("string").alias("columnZ"),
}
dfInputColumnized.write.parquet("C:/dfInputColumnized")
```

However this gives me the following error

> 2018-12-11 13:26:31.331 ERROR   --- [rker for task 7]
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils              : Aborting task
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63  at
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.substringSQL(UTF8String.java:309)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> 2018-12-11 13:26:33.323 ERROR   --- [rker for task 7]
>   o.a.s.s.e.datasources.FileFormatWriter   : Job job_20181211132630_0000
>   aborted. 2018-12-11 13:26:33.334 ERROR   --- [rker for task 7]
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor       : Exception in task 7.0 in
>   stage 0.0 (TID 7)
>
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.

I'm guessing this is due to bad records so I tried to catch it like this:

```
val dfRawInput = spark.read.text("C:/input.txt")
val dfInputColumnized = {
        dfRawInput
          .withColumn("column1",when(length($"value")>=lit(8),$"value".substr(1,8)).otherwise(null))
          .withColumn("column2",when(length($"value")>=lit(13),$"value".substr(9,5)).otherwise(null))
          ...
          .withColumn("columnZ",when(length($"value")>=lit(x+y-1),$"value".substr(x,y)).otherwise(null))
}
dfInputColumnized.write.parquet("C:/dfInputColumnized")
```

The error now reads:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
>
> 2018-12-11 13:30:45.904 ERROR   --- [ker for task 24]
>   o.a.s.s.e.datasources.FileFormatWriter   : Job job_20181211104644_0006
>   aborted. 2018-12-11 13:30:45.904 ERROR   --- [ker for task 24]
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor       : Exception in task 7.0 in
>   stage 6.0 (TID 24)
>
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null

Is it indeed due to corrupt rows?
Is there a way to skip those using Spark?
Is there a better way to go about this? (I'm not necessarily bound to Spark)

Comment: Why not filter on the record length (character count) and only apply map functions which match the desired format?

Comment: @user238607 Thanks for you reply. I added .filter(length($"value")>=x+y-1) but alas to no avail

Comment: I didn't mean that. I mean `correctdf = dfRawInput.filter(length($"value") > expectedLenght)` Then applying the column transformation.

Comment: If your data is not big, you can use pandas functions mentioned here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: @user238607 I did this and the error remains. I also tried dfRawInput.count which results in '37,098,824' and then correctdf.count and this also resulted in the "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63" error. Is '37,098,824' to big for pandas functions?

Comment: To add some clarity maybe to user238607 otherwise fine answer: given `$"value".substr(x,y)` is your last line and therefor `y` is the least `value` - string length you need to not have your code throw an ArrayOutOfBounds, you should check if `length(value) >=y`. That should fix it.

Comment: @ElmarMacek substr takes two arguments: substr(startPos: Int, len: Int) so it is actually length(value)>=x+y-1.

Comment: try with `.otherwise(lit(null: String))` . Looking at the logs, the newer error appears when writing, and it's probably because when creating null values you have to lift them with `lit`.

Comment: @BobGrijpstra Thanks for clarifying. Somehow i mixed up `y` with the endposition of the substring you want to extract. ;-)